# Speeding up the vision.VideoFileReader function for movieprocessing matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, optimization

I have movies that are 60 seconds long and I am processing them to pull out moving objects. I can do this by performing a background subtraction, filtering the image, and using blob analyzer.

The problem is that the overall process is slow as pulling frames from the video is the most time consuming part with 44.96 taking up more than half of the time processing the video. I used `profile viewer` to see the timing.

If you look at my function, I am just using the `Vision` module to load the video and `step` to move through the video. Is there a way to speed this up.?

[image]

```
Log_filter = fspecial('log', filterdot, thresh); % fspecial creat predefined filter.Return a filter.

tic
ii = 1;

bkgd = gpuArray(gh.Bkgd);

while ~isDone(gh.Video.reader)
    frame = gh.readFrame();
    gframe = gpuArray(frame);
    img_temp = double(rgb2gray(gframe));

    subbk = img_temp - bkgd;

    img_LOG = imfilter(subbk, Log_filter, 'symmetric', 'conv');
    img_LOG = img_LOG>.5;
    [~, centroids, ~] = gh.Video.blobAnalyser.step(gather(img_LOG));
    gh.Tracks.centroids{ii} = centroids;
    ii = ii+1;
    toc
end
gh.Video.info.NumberOfFrames = ii-1;
gh.ResetVideo
display('Dots extracted')
```

Here is my function to pull frames

[image]

```
function frame = readFrame(gh)
    frame = gh.Video.reader.step();
end
```

Comment: I am doubtful anymore speed up is possible in VideoFileReader. It should be using codecs installed on your system to get the video frame.

Comment: could I use opencv to pull the frames? would that be faster?

Comment: I do not know for sure. If majority of time is spent in video decoding then it may not help much as those libraries are usually highly optimized.